# Capture Audio media Phonegap error code 3

Tags: cordova, audio, phonegap, microphone

I coded an application with phonegap, I used the plugin cordova-media-capture and when using the apk, the use of the microphone returns me the error code 3.

I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please post your code. see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my html code for more details:

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-5"></div>
     <div class="col-90">
    <a href="" class="button button-big button-fill" id="MicrophoneBtnTakeId"><i class="f7-icons">mic</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5"></div>
</div>
```

then also my js code:

```
    $$('#MicrophoneBtnTakeId').on('click', function() {

        // capture error callback
        var captureError = function(error) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
            $$('#TxtMicrophoneErrorAppClickId').show();
            $$('#SoundRecorderBtnAppId').show();
        };

        // start audio capture
        navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError);

        var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
            var i, path, len;
            for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
            }
        }
       });
```

Hopefully this will help those who want to help me solve this problem.

Thank you